# Why should the fields specified in field attribute of the force:recordData component have permission set

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am building a lightning component in which I am using force:recordData component. I noticed that when I use field attribute with fields from the object and even if one of the fields does not have read access it return a null object when fetched. What is the reason for this? I understand if we fetch a field for which we don't have access, we should get a NULL value returned. But if we are fetching a field that has access then why should a NULL be returned?

Ex:

Scenario 1:

Name, NumberOfEmployees => Read Access

Custom_Field1__c, Custom_Field2__c => No Access

**Component:**

```
<aura:attribute name="account" type="Object" />
  <force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader"
    fields="Name, NumberOfEmployees, Custom_Field1__c, Custom_Field2__c"
    recordId="{!v.recordId}"
    targetFields="{!v.account}"
    targetError="{!v.recordError}"
    mode="VIEW"
    />
```

**Controller**

```
var numberofemployees = component.get("v.account.NumberOfEmployees");
console.log('Number of employees: ', numberofemployees); => NULL (returns NULL even when NumberOfEmployees has read access)

console.log('Account: ', component.get("v.account")); => NULL (returns NULL on the object)
```

Scenario 2:

Name, NumberOfEmployees => Read Access

Custom_Field1__c, Custom_Field2__c => Read Access

#Same code as above

```
console.log('Number of employees: ', numberofemployees); => #value (returns a value)

console.log('Account: ', component.get("v.account")); => Proxy {} (returns a value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying API returns a fatal error when you try to query a record with fields you don't have access to, rather than just returning the fields you do have access to. If you check the `targetError`, you'll see an error like *No such column 'Custom_Field1__c' exists on entity 'Account'.* Consider using `layoutType="FULL"` if you want to just get all fields for which the user has access to.

Comment: Thanks, @sfdcfox this is super helpful. But is this a valid behavior? Shouldn't we be able to fetch the fields which have access, even if other specified fields don't have access?

Comment: @nevrekar_amey It is the way it's designed, for better or for worse. Yes, I'd rather we just be able to specify any fields we want, and it just filters out fields that are not accessible, but that's not the API we have. The wildcard selector (layoutType="FULL") is the best we can do today.